# Why wont CMD work

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I am using CMD but when ever I want to go to a specific location the response I get is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file. This happens no matter what location I choose to go to, even desktop, any ideas why this is happening?

for example
C:\Users\Hassan> is how it open and then when i type Desktop it displays 
desktop is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Comment: And **what** command do you use to go to **which** specific location? Some commands you used would clarify a lot in this question. You can use the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/671691/edit)-link to edit your question.

Comment: I think you should take the time to Google up on how to use the terminal. There is a set of commands you have to execute to do these things. One cannot just write `Desktop` to be moved there. It has to be combined with a valid command.

Comment: No offense, but you clearly don’t know much/anything about the command-prompt, which begs the question *why are you using it at all?* If you’re trying to do something *specific*, then you should ask *that* instead. If you’re simply trying to learn to use the command-prompt in general, then you should [study](http://ss64.com/nt/) [up](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx) [on](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2632) [it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx). We can help with the former, not the latter; this isn’t a tutorial site.

Answer (score 3):

When it opens with `C:\Users\Hassan>` you need to type commands to do something.

For example if you want to go to your desktop you should type `CD Desktop` + <kbd>enter</kbd>

Now you have `C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop>` and you could use `DIR` + <kbd>enter</kbd> to see the content.

But what do you want to do there if you don't know any commands?

[Here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/cmd-prompt.html) is a command-line tutorial. And [here](http://people.uncw.edu/pattersone/121/labs/L1_MSDOS_Primer.pdf) is a PDF which might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The command prompt helpfully displays "*'Desktop' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file,*" because 'Desktop' is not a command, operable program or batch file and cmd expects one of those things. The command to change directory is `cd` and the line I presume you're looking for is `cd Desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft® Windows Command Prompt** isn't like the `fish` shell, prepend a `cd` with a space, before `Desktop` for it to do the intended.